# Constraining UIImageView height to respect dynamic UILabel height in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a UITableView filled with one type of custom UITableViewCell. Each cell contains a **title** (UILabel), **subtitle** (UILabel), and **thumbnail** (UIImageView), as shown below.

[image: prototype cell visual]

The widths of all three subviews are fixed, but only the subtitle label has a fixed height. The title label's height is dynamic according to the amount of text. I have set the title label's `numberOfLines` to 0 to reflect this.

**My objective**: The height of the cell should be determined by the height of the title label. In other words, the cell height should be the sum of the two labels' heights plus the three vertical padding gaps. The image height should be set to the resulting height of the cell.

**My current implementation**: I have set the following autolayout constraints:

- Thumbnail is pegged to superview on top, left and bottom
- Thumbnails width is proportional to superview width by a multiple of 0.2
- Thumbnail is pegged on its right side to title and subtitle (trailing space = 8)
- Title is pegged to superview on top and right (trailing space = 8)
- Title is pegged on its bottom to subtitle (trailing space = 8)
- Title height is greater than or equal to 24
- Subtitle is pegged to superview on right and bottom (trailing space = 8)
- Subtitle height is equal to 20

Additionally:

- Title `numberOfLines` = 0
- Thumbnail `contentMode` = Aspect Fill
- Thumbnail `clipToBounds` = true

**The problem**: The image height does not respect the height of the labels, so the height of the cell is set to the full height of the image and the title label is stretched vertically. This is understandable given the constraints I have used, but is not what I want to happen.

**My question**: How do I constrain the UIImageView's height to respect the cell height (determined by dynamic label height), instead of having the cell height respect the UIImageView height?

**My Environment**:

- Xcode 10
- iOS 11 & 12
- Swift 4.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting `thumbnail` vertical `compression resistance` lower than `title` vertical `hugging priority`. In code it'll look like this:

```
    thumbnail.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
    titleLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also be setting the priorities for the labels also? So that in case the image view is bigger, then the appropriate label is resized and the other one left one? Or do they both equally resized if no priorities are set?

Comment: In question the subtitle has fixed height set with height constraint so there's no need for it. In other case yes, we'd have to change some priorities for it too

Answer (score 2):

I'll explain the vertical constraints to make this possible.

- Pin the top of the label to the contentView with enough padding so that image view stays inside it.
- Pin the top of the subtitleLabel to the bottom of the titleLabel.
- Pin the bottom of the subtitle similarly to the bottom of the contentView, so that the image view stays inside it.

Your cell now has a height based on the above constraints. Now you just have to make sure you place the image view inside this height.

- Pin the top of the thumbnail to the top of the label, bottom to the bottom of the subtitle label.

Example:

- titleLabel.top -> contentView.top + 10
- subtitleLabel.top -> titleLabel.bottom + 5
- subtitleLabel.bottom -> contentView.bottom - 10
- imageView.top -> titleLabel.top - 5
- imageView.bottom -> subtitleLabel.bottom + 5

Comment: This does work, however I am opting for the other solution as it seems cleaner for my use case.

Comment: @WillB i understand that it is shorter, but how is it cleaner?

Comment: it isn't by much at all really. I just had to pick one and, while both solutions were equally capable, for whatever reason I liked the idea of adjusting the compression resistance and hugging priority more than messing with autolayout any more than I had to.

Comment: @WillB The autolayout code doesn't break any of your constraints, so no extra calculation checking which constraints need to be broken depending on the hugging priority will happen at runtime which makes the autolayout code faster IMO. Agreed the other answer is easier, but IMO not optimal.

Comment: I'll admit I was tired and so the shorter solution was naturally preferable after wrestling with AL all day. I'm planning to look into this solution further when I get a chance. Thanks again!

Comment: @WillB i understand :'D I've been there as well. Just because you can use a tape instead of a nail to hold something in place doesn't mean it's the best. That's all i'm saying ;)

Comment: Haha, duly noted!

Comment: Let's imagine in your example ImageView has intrinsicSize.height = 100,  title.intrinsicSize.height = 20 and subtitle.height = 10. In this case cell height will be 110  - defined by image view height. title height will be set to 75 due to the fact that its' hugging priority is lower than thumbnails' compression resistance. All constraints seem to be satisfied. And we didn't get the desired result. Am I missing something? Still same amount of constraints have to be broken according to their priorities, so why it should be more optimal?

Comment: @AntonFilimonov in my logic imageview doesn’t take the intrinsic size, instead takes the height defined by the labels. So the constraints calculations which would be performed by the parameters you set would not even be needed here. The only problem would be how the image would look for the constraints set.

Comment: Which constraints prevent taking into account intrinsic size of the thumbnail? alignment constraints just tell that top and bottom edges of thumbnail should be aligned to edges of labels. And those alignment constraints could be satisfied together with intrinsic size of image view

Comment: @AntonFilimonov _"And those alignment constraints could be satisfied together with intrinsic size of image view"_ ohh can you explain further. Maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: I mean, `imageView.top -> titleLabel.top - 5` doesn't mean that top edge of image view depends on top edge of label. It's an equation which sets relationship between those edges. And it's totally the same as `titleLabel.top -> imageView.top + 5` and it doesn't prevent calculating intrinsic size of any of these views

Comment: @AntonFilimonov ok, i understand now. So what would be happen if i do not set the priority for anything and just use the logic to write autolayout code. Which intrinsic size would have priority?

Comment: And constraints are not evaluated in some order, but all together, so intrinsic size always take place (maybe except just cases when size is set directly by height/width constraint) so if there are no constraints with higher priority (than hugging priority/compression resistance) that could not be satisfied respecting intrinsic size, that size will be taken into account

Comment: By default higher intrinsic size is used because default compression resistance is higher than default hugging priority

Comment: @AntonFilimonov wow i learnt a lot. So this means my answer is actually not good. I would need to attach the top and bottom of the image to the top and bottom of the contentview and then set the priorities like you said correct? Can you also add the verticals constraints needed in your answer to make the priorities work exactly as needed?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Actually, all other constraints needed are described in the question. And also your variant of constraints would work with changed priorities (I'd prefer constraints related to superview instead of those related to other views because they are easier to read)

Comment: @AntonFilimonov let's say the image size is really small. Smaller than the labels' intrinsic size combined and i have set the vertical constraints relative to the contentview. Where would it attach itself to? Since the vertical constraints are going to be ignored because of the priorities i set.

Comment: Let's say you've set `imageView.top = superview.top + 5` and `imageView.bottom = superview.bottom - 5` and all other constraints are set like in your example and subtitle.width constraint is set to 10 and you don't change default intrinsic size priorities. Than if `title.intrinsicSize.height = 50` and `imageView.intrinsicSize.height = 20` than cell height will be 70 (according to title height and top and bottom constraints) and imageView.height will be set to 60 to satisfy top and bottom constraints together with titles' `contentCompressionResistance`

Comment: @AntonFilimonov ah i realize my folly now. Mine doesn't account for the imageView being bigger than the label size.